# youtube api - loop throug huge data

Tags: youtube-api

I need to retrieve the 'view count' for each video channel , and I’m using this [library](https://github.com/jimdoescode/CodeIgniter-YouTube-API-Library)  .
this is my code

okay the code works fine and print me the view count foreach video , except that i got  these warnings with some other videos without printing the view count

**A PHP Error was encountered Severity:** Warning Message:

- simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity:
  line 547: parser error : attributes construct error
- Message:
  simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]:
  outube_gdata'/>

  Message:
  simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^

  Message:
  simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity:
  line 547: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag link line 547

  Message: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]:
  outube_gdata'/>

how can i deal with this large number of videos and channels without causing this warning msgs and lost in time , cause if i tried the same code on one channel with fewer videos i  got no errors

```
$channels=array('google','apple','mac','xyz','abc','test');
for ($j=0; $j<count($channels) $j++)
{

$JSON = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/".$channels[$j]."/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=0");
$JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
    $total_videos = $JSON_Data->{'data'}->{'totalItems'};

    for($i=1; $i<=$total_videos; )
    {
        $this->get_userfeed($channels[$j],$maxresult=20,$start=$i);
        $i+=20;
    }

}

public function get_userfeed($ch_id,$maxresult=10,$start=0,$do=null)
{

    $output = $this->youtube->getUserUploads($ch_id, array('max-results'=>$maxresult,'start-index'=>$start));
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($output);

    // single entry for testing
    foreach($xml->entry as $entry)
    {
    foreach($entry->id as $key=>$val)
    {
    $id = explode('videos/', (string)$val);

    $JSON = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$id[1]."?v=2&alt=json");
    $JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
    $v_count = $JSON_Data->{'entry'}->{'yt$statistics'}->{'viewCount'};
    if($v_count == NULL) $v_count =0;

    echo $v_count;
    // store the v_count into database

    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a few things wrong.

First off, if you want to minimize the number of calls you're making to the API, you should be setting `max-results=50`, which is the largest value that the API supports.

Second, I don't understand why you're making individual calls to `http://.../videos/VIDEO_ID` to retrieve the statistics for each video, since that information is already returned as part of the video entries you're getting from the `http://.../users/USER_ID/uploads` feed. You can just store the values returned by that feed and avoid having to make all those additional calls to retrieve each video.

Finally, the underlying issue is almost certainly that you're running into quota errors, and you can read more about them at http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/02/best-practices-for-avoiding-quota.html

Taking any of the steps I mention should cut down on the total requests that you're making and potentially get around any quota problems, but you should familiarize yourself with the quota system anyway.

Comment: thank you jeff so much . i did what u said ,you've saved my time .